On the condition of positive semidefiniteness of a matrix
According to  Wikipedia,

$\textbf{Wikipedia definition:}$ an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix $M$ is positive semidefinite if and only
if it can be decomposed as a product $M = BB^*$ where $*$ is the
conjugate-transpose operation.

My question: Is the same true if $M = C^*C$? That is, does the following statement also hold

$\textbf{My statement:}$ an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix $M$ is positive semidefinite if and only if it can be decomposed as a product $M = C^* C$ where $*$ is the conjugate-transpose operation

I understand if we just define $B=C^*$ then it follows immediately. But then why is it that the condition is always (as far as I could search) given as $M = C^*C$?

I mean, the two are completely equivalent. The first author to use the terminology probably liked writing $C^\ast C$ more than they liked writing $CC^\ast$, maybe? There isn’t really any reason to use one above the other.
